Insert data to supabase with python
I would like to import some data to a supabase using Python. I followed the documentation like here, which suggests that we can use the supabase.table attribute to .insert data. I tried the following code which doesn't work:
import supabase

response = (
    supabase.table("user_results")
    .insert({"id": 1, "Date": "Denmark",
             "Race": "1",
             "Track": "Mario Kart Stadium",
             "Finish": "1"})
    .execute()
)

Output:
AttributeError: module 'supabase' has no attribute 'table'

I do understand the error, but I don't understand why this is not working. I find it really confusing how we can simply insert some data to a supabase using python. So I was wondering if anyone knows how to insert data to a supabase?

For reference, my database looks like this in supabase:


To insert data to supabase table use the snippet:
from supabase import Client, create_client

supabase_client: Client = create_client(API_URL, API_KEY)
response = (
    supabase_client.from_("table_name")
    .insert(
        [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "Date": "Denmark",
                "Race": "1",
                "Track": "Mario Kart Stadium",
                "Finish": "1",
            }
        ]
    )
    .execute()
)

API_KEY and API_URL you will find in supabase settings
supabase version - 2.4.6
P.S. Using it in my projects
Update:
I have found that you can use .table as well, because its just alias for from_. But you should init supabase client before.
Check the link with code: enter link description here

It looks like you haven't properly installed the supabase package from Pip.
Please check the Supabase documentation for detailed installation instructions: Supabase Documentation - Installing.
